# Data Communication between two linux machines using wlan

Tags: linux, sockets, wifi

I am trying to communicate a text data between two Linux machines using wlan.

Can it be achieved by socket programming in c, or is there any other method.

Please suggest me in this regard.

Regards,
Ajith

Comment: Do you want to use it (for some other purpose eventually)or want to write code to get this accomplished?

Comment: I want to write a small application code in 'c' to send one text data from server(Linux) to the client machine(Linux) and send an acknowledge back to server after the data is received at client.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://www.cs.utah.edu/~swalton/listings/sockets/programs/part1/chap4/connected-peer.c) might be helpful if you want to write something of your own. This uses UDP protocol. As per your comment, I don't understand why a well established server like Apache won't work for you? If it does and you *want* to write something like it, why not read the [source code](http://www.apache.org/dev/version-control.html)?

Also take a look at [this](http://www.jmarshall.com/easy/http/).